# how to remove unknown values in MDX

Tags: ssas

I had some result like

```
All          $8,668,386,597.68  
(Unknown)    $659,489,688.12    
(Unknown)    $659,489,688.12    
10104 Cash   $1,431,587.63  
10105 Cash   $103,808,884.17
```

Here i need to remove " (Unknown) "  Values.Could any one Help me out

Answer (score 1):

Unknown indicates that you had a foreign key in your fact for which there was a null value or no dimension with that key. If, possible, I would figure out why you have orphaned fact rows and fix the data so the unknown member doesn't have values associated with it. If the unknowns are expected and you really do want to remove them, you can change the settings in the dimension properties.

Change the Unknown Member property to Hidden.

Here is a link for more info: [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2011/01/10/ssas-*1320*-hiding-unknown-member/](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2011/01/10/ssas-_1320_-hiding-unknown-member/)